# Utilização de elementos de um Form dentro de uma função

Tags: c++

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no C++ Builder que possui um `Form` que contém elementos como `ListBox`, botões, `Labels`, etc.

Consigo realizar a configuração dos eventos de cada um desses elementos (`onClick`, `onEnter`, `onExit`...) dentro de um arquivo `.cpp`, porém quando tento criar uma função dentro deste mesmo arquivo `.cpp` que acesse as propriedades dos elementos (`Visible`, `Enabled`, `Caption`, etc.) obtenho um erro:

> "undefined symbol".

Como faço para utilizar os elementos contidos em um Form dentro de uma função criada por mim.

Segue código do problema.

```
//Função criada por mim, dentro da Unit1.cpp que contem o Form1 no qual está o ListBox1

void funcao(AnsiString parametro){ 

 ...
 ListBox1->Items->Add("ItemParaListBox"); //Essa linha gera o erro "undefined symbol ListBox1"

}

//Função de fastcall realizada para edição de evento do elemento dentro da mesma Unit1.cpp

void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn11Click(TObject *Sender){

...
ListBox1->Items->Add("ItemParaListBox"); //Funciona normalmente

}
```

Comment: Se você não colocar detalhes de como está utilizando o que fica difícil responder alguma coisa.

Comment: Sem ter o seu código é trabalho impossível adivinhar qual é o erro. Considere fazer um [**exemplo mínimo verificável**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel).

Comment: Aparentemente o problema é que a sua função não é um método da classe `TForm1`, e por isso não consegue acessar os membros dessa classe (entre eles, o tal `ListBox1`).